# Apache Rewrite Question: Similar url patterns

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to tidy up the urls on my site. I have written the following rules. For

```
index.php?id=work&pid=work-item 
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?id=$1&pid=$2 [L]
```

Which works and looks like this:

```
 /work/work-item/
```

Then for:

```
index.php?id=work&tag=1
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?id=$1&tag=$2 [L]
```

Which also works but breaks the first rule. Does anyone have any ideas for a solution.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a `RewriteCond` in order to make the rewrite rule conditional and not apply to anything that matches your regex.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=...$
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?id=$1&pid=$2 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tag=...$
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?id=$1&tag=$2 [L]
```